# Optimised method to find all solutions of inequality

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, inequality

I am trying to find the number of solutions of inequality 
`c > (a+(b^2)−1)/(a−1)`

subject to constraints `2<=a<=A, 1<=b<=B, 1<=c<=C`.

The approach I am using till now is to use a nested loop with outer loop for *a* and inner loop for `b`. I am trying to find ways to optimize my approach since `A` can be as large as `10^9`.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use numpy for vectorized operations. You can do something like this ->

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(2,A)
b = np.arange(1,B)
a1 = a.repeat(len(b), axis=0)
b1 = b.repeat(len(a), axis=0)

rhs = (a1 + (b1**2) -1) / (a1 - 1)
```

Comment: Not experienced with numpy so cannot point out the fault, but the list named rhs isn't giving the right values of c. Also, it still takes a lot of time.